# Не прогружаются стили css

Tags: css, http, https

У меня есть заказчик с Турции и у него сайт выглядит так как будто там не прогрузился CSS, а у меня всё норм долго не мог понять в чём проблема пока не подключил прокси Турецкого сервера и появилась та самая беда. Важный нюанс что когда используешь httpS прокси то всё норм, а когда обычный то всё плохо. Я предположил, что если поставить на сайт ssl сертификат то всё заработает, но заказчика это не устраивает. Кто то с этим сталкивался, что делать?

[Сайт](http://thatjoker.com)

[image: Норм сайт]

[image: Плохой сайт]

Comment: Как включен css в html?

Comment: @Sheridan <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">, сам css написан на Sass и там есть ещё карта стилей, думаете в этом может быть проблема?

Comment: Уже увидел - ссылку не заметил. Пока идей нет :(

Comment: Печально я совсем растерянный. Человек не хочет отдавать деньги за сайт,  хотя я ему объяснил мол проблема в хостинге, а не в сайте. Я ставил на проверку на хостинге reg.ru и там всё работает как часы. :(

Comment: Ошибки в консоле или логах есть?

Answer (score 0):

Просто человек не почистил кэш на сервере, который ко всему был его личным)